# How to increase the quantity using Shopping cart Content webpart

Tags: kentico

I need feature in checkout page where used should be able to increase/decrease/delete the cart items. I used ShoppingCartContent webpart for this. There is a text box to change the number of quantity but what happens next? how the price and quantity get updated. I can't see any button or controls which update the price or quantity in the cart. Please let me know if you have any inputs on this.
Thanks, Sharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a control called CartItemUnits inside your transformation
(ecommercesite.transformations.checkoutshoppingcartitem):

```
<%@ Register Src="~/CMSModules/Ecommerce/Controls/Checkout/CartItemUnits.ascx" TagName="CartItemUnits" TagPrefix="cms" %>

<cms:CartItemUnits runat="server" CartItemID='<%# Eval("CartItemID")%>' UnitFormControlName="TextBoxControl" ShowUpdate="true" ImageURL="~/App_Themes/EcommerceSite/Images/Ecommerce/checkout_refresh.png"  ControlType="image" />
```

This CartItemsUnites  has ControlType property that can be image or button, I suggest switch to button i.e. `ControlType="button"` You probably missing the "refresh" image and make sure you have `ShowUpdate="true"` i.e.:

```
<cms:CartItemUnits runat="server" CartItemID='<%# Eval("CartItemID")%>' UnitFormControlName="TextBoxControl" ShowUpdate="true"  ControlType="button" />
```

It should give text box with #of units and update button nex to it

Comment: Thank you Shof, this fixed my issue